# Build and run net5 code from VSIX project

Tags: vsix

I am inside a VSIX extension for visual studio and the opened project is a net5 project.

I have to get the a source code of a class, build it, execute and get the result of a method call of the compiled class.

The problem is that VSIX project runs under net framework while the class i have to compile and execute is net5.

The only way i found is compile the class inside a net5 executable, run it and wait the result wrote in a knowed file path(not yet tryed).

Of course it is a bad solution so i'd like to ask if i have other choices

Comment: I just parse the text output from stdout, avoids having to write a file

Comment: ErikEJ tanks for the idea